# Invalid_grant when requesting Access token MS Graph

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, access-token

thanks for reading this.

I've a problem obtaining an access token for MS Graph using Postman. I've been reading similar posts on stackoverflow, but so far, without success. In the following I added some screenshots that contain (I believe) all the information needed for this process.

1. Screenshot of application permissions:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lyM2.png
2. The link I use to obtain an access-code:

   [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{Tenant](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7BTenant) ID}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
   client_id=3ef3343a-ab22-4c50-12ae2a2d7c67
   &response_type=code
   &redirect_uri=https://localhost:8080
   &response_mode=query
   &scope=offline_access%20user.read
   &state=12345

3)After following this link I give permission and receive a code, which I use in the following postman call: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJv2b.png

I had no problem obtaining the access token without a user, but unfortunately, I need more than just the application permissions. I hope someone can help me!

Thanks for your time!

Comment: The error states the request you made is not correct. Have you checked the request in Fiddler? It should look something line [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#request-an-access-token).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to delete the "code=" in `code` of postman call, it looks like "OAAABAAAAiL9Kn.....". `code` is just the value of "code" from `/authorize` endpoint. The others all looks correct.

---

**UPDATE:**

I tried with the steps in your issue, it worked well.

Permissions:

[image]

Get authorization code:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id={client-id}
&response_type=code 
&redirect_uri=https://localhost:44300/
&response_mode=query 
&scope=offline_access%20user.read 
&state=12345
```

Receive the code:

```
https://localhost:44300/?code=0.ATcATqvJ...vv1MbCO6MN_uCAA&state=12345&session_state=7ac58b8f-b2af-45fa-be4b-0b2c2a003e2e
```

**Code is `0.ATcATqvJ...vv1MbCO6MN_uCAA` from the pervious.**

Request in Postman:

[image]

Comment: Hello Pamela, thanks for your answer. I tried it without Code= too, but that didn't  work either (unfortunately it slipped in in this example).

Comment: Hi, @AlexanderBeBrave. This error occurs when the `code` is incorrect. Please follow my UPDATE to check your code. Make sure `&state=12345&session_state=xxxx` is deleted. Reproduce it with incorrect code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKfTx.png.

Comment: Hello Pamela, thanks so much. I copied in the '&state=123345' in all my requests... Finally it's working now! Awesome that you spend time on helping others!

Comment: My pleasure! Glad to know that :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot generate a single token both Delegated ([with a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user?view=graph-rest-1.0)) and Application ([without a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service?view=graph-rest-1.0)). You'll need to make two separate requests.

For generating a Delegated token, you first need to retrieve an Authorization Code (i.e. the  `authrorization_code` grant). This is done by redirecting the user to the following address (line breaks are for readability only)

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=[APPLICATION ID]&
response_type=code&
redirect_uri=[REDIRECT URI]&
scope=[SCOPE]
```

This will return an Authorization Code to the address you specified in the `redirect_uri` parameter (note that this address must *also* be included in your app registration). You then take this code an `POST` it to the `/token` endpoint like this:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=authorization_code&
code=[AUTHORIZATION CODE]&
client_id=[APPLICATION ID]&
client_secret=[PASSWORD]&
scope=[SCOPE]&
redirect_uri=[REDIRECT URI]
```

For Application tokens, you simply skip the authorization code step and `POST` to the `/token` endpoint directly:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantDomain}/oauth2/v2.0/token
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=client_credentials&
client_id=[APPLICATION ID]&
client_secret=[PASSWORD]&
scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
```

Comment: Hello Marc, thanks a lot for your time. I got it working now... the issue was that I used the wrong part of the code. But thanks a lot and your post is very clear!